# Badge for profile views must be on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, support, badges

```
Participation Badges
  Autobiographer  
  Caucus 
  Commentator 
  Pundit  
  Enthusiast
  Mortarboard 
  Epic  
  Legendary 
  Precognitive 
  Yearling 
  etc...
```

But why is there no badge for the number of profile views?

There must be a badge for profile views on Stack Overflow.

Comment: What makes you say that?

Comment: I'm sure that your profile would have been quite a number of times today.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Badges are awarded, basically, in order to encourage participation, and moreover, positive behaviors, in the site - e.g., asking (good) questions, answering, reviewing, etc.

I don't think profile views would be a good fit here - there's nothing productive, really, a user can do to encourage others to view his profile (besides actively participating, which is already awarded by the reputation system, and many other badges).

Another consideration against such a badge would be that such a badge could inadvertently reward bad behavior. Change your username to `I_hate_<some racial slur>`, and you'll get dozens of profile views of people trying to understand who this a** is. Hardly a behavior worthy of a badge.

NOTES:

1. Thanks @RobertP for the feedback. The second paragraph was amended
   to include his input from the comments.
2. As @0x7fffffff commented, running for mod is a productive type of behavior that would attract profile views, so the statement above should be taken with a grain of salt.

Comment: There's actually an above board way to quickly boost profile views. Running for mod tends to attract a lot of attention.

Comment: @RobertP. Perhaps I should rephrase - "there's nothing **productive**, really, a user can do to encourage others to view his profile."